# Node JS with Express leaking memory

Tags: node.js, express, out-of-memory, amazon-ecs

I am new to `Node JS`.  I have a Node JS + Express app that is causing a `Docker container` to repeatedly stop with exit code 137 - out of memory error every 5-10 minutes.

The app could not be more simple serving up static html, css, js and images

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8080

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname + "/public" } );
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`web app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Directory structure

```
--root
    server.js
    --public
        index.html
        --css
        --js
        --img
```

The host is an `ECS EC2 instance - T2 small with 2Gb memory`.  The container task allocation 1024 MiB of memory.

Dockerfile

```
# from nodes 12 image 
FROM node:12
MAINTAINER coco


# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app


# Install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./


RUN npm install


# Bundle app source - copy all files/folders in current directory
COPY . .


# Specify ports
EXPOSE 8080


# Run the app
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

> What about this Node app is causing a memory leak?  Though, it may be [express that's leaking](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3552).  I'm using `express 4.17.1`

Comment: It seems unlikely that anything about this app is causing a memory leak.  It seems more likely that your app is just trying to use more memory than you've allocated for it.  nodejs server instances are not small.  A leak is something that gets progressively larger over time.  Memory usage is not the same thing as memory leaks.  I would suggest temporarily allocating more memory to the server (so it doesn't halt) and then watch its memory usage over time.

Comment: What docker image(s) are you using?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone  FROM node:12

Comment: @jfriend00  What would you suggest?  I  can't seem to find any guidance on how big a Node server should be.  If you could point me to some resources that cover this it would be appreciated.  Also, how would it be using so much memory.  Those same html and asset files work in `Tomcat` with 512KiB and have never run over on memory.  Perhaps `Node` or `Express` are leaky?

Comment: Are you aware the host os uses resources prob around 256mb more if ubuntu, then you have a docker image as you say node:12 which is 12.18.3-stretch which is running debian which has its own os base ram usage which maybe around 256mb.. then you have the caches it all can add up before you even run anything. Check `top`, then check the usage of the container `docker stats e164718fe583` etc.. if your stuck on ram add swap, at least the container wont crash

Comment: `npm install` is not ram friendly either use about 200mb ram for a few seconds

Comment: @LawrenceCherone   That runs during the container build, not during runtime.  The container runs on an Amazon image, not Ubuntu - that is good to know though thank you.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone  I run this static web with Tomcat on a T2 micro instance - that's 1GiB of RAM.  So, what I am understanding currently is that `Node` with `Express` are way more greedy than `Tomcat`.  This problem is on a T2 small instance with twice the RAM of the Tomcat instance.  Tomcat instance has never given me grief.